# OpenCV: extractor->descriptorSize() - Segfault

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, feature-descriptor

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/) for object detection but I stuck at the beginning.

Until now my code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
    //Mat training_descriptors(1, extractor->descriptorSize(), extractor->descriptorType());

    extractor->descriptorSize();

    return 0;
}
```

The following line `extractor->descriptorSize();` gives a Segmentation fault (core dumped) and I don't know why. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: 1. try to check: `extractor.empty();` (there might have been no instance created.) 2. try to add a `initModule_nonfree();` line before calling that (if you're using opencv2.4) 3. check, if there's an opencv_nonfree.so or such at all (some package managers just don't distribute it)

Comment: extractor.empty() returns 1. When I add initModule_nonfree(); I can't compile (‘initModule_nonfree’ was not declared in this scope)

Comment: I just found out that the nonfree module is not installed. I'm installing it right now and I'll see what will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the nonfree module of OpenCV was not installed. After installation I included the nonfree library `#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>` and then called `cv::initModule_nonfree();`. The problem is solved.